# vb.net interface signature syntax

Tags: vb.net, interface

This code below makes VS complain about 2 things:

1. `IComparer` interface must implement `Compare(...)`
2. `Implements...` is not valid  within a method/multiline lambda (inside the function).

So what's wrong with it? The signature is correct, making the function a lambda oneliner didn't help. It's the same syntax as in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Collections.IComparer%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) anyway:

```
Public Class ColorSorter : Implements Collections.IComparer
    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer
        Implements Collections.IComparer.Compare

        Dim cx As Drawing.Color, cy As Drawing.Color
        Dim hx As Single, hy As Single, sx As Single, sy As Single, bx As Single, by As Single

        cx = DirectCast(x, Drawing.SolidBrush).Color
        cy = DirectCast(y, Drawing.SolidBrush).Color
        sx = cx.GetSaturation()
        sy = cy.GetSaturation()
        hx = cx.GetHue()
        hy = cy.GetHue()
        bx = cx.GetBrightness()
        by = cy.GetBrightness()

        If hx < hy Then : Return -1
        ElseIf hx > hy Then : Return 1
        Else
            If sx < sy Then : Return -1
            ElseIf sx > sy Then : Return 1
            Else
                If bx < by Then : Return -1
                ElseIf bx > by Then : Return 1
                Else : Return 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB there is no statement terminator (like `;` in C#), so every line is a statement. That's why you can't place *New Line* in some places like in C#. And that's why your code cannot be compiled.

Change your method declaration to one line:

```
Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer  Implements Collections.IComparer.Compare
```

Or add `_` at the end of first line to tell compiler it's not the end of statement and it should merge it with next line before compilation:

```
Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer _
  Implements Collections.IComparer.Compare
```

Comment: This is true almost all of the time, there are some instances where you are not required to explicitly state a line continuation as described in the [Implicit Line Continuation section of Statements in Visual Basic 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/865x40k4(v=vs.100).aspx). In this particular case, you are correct that the OP needs the line continuation.

Answer (score 1):

Try puttting it in one line, or include the underscore character:

```
Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer _
    Implements Collections.IComparer.Compare
```

VB.Net doesn't know those two lines are connected without that underscore character.

Comment: This is true almost all of the time, there are some instances where you are not required to explicitly state a line continuation as described in the [Implicit Line Continuation section of Statements in Visual Basic 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/865x40k4(v=vs.100).aspx). In this particular case, you are correct that the OP needs the line continuation.